Assistance Required: Streamlit Output Link Not Accessible in Colab
I've been experiencing difficulties with integrating Streamlit into Colab. Specifically, when attempting to access the Streamlit output via the provided server link, I'm consistently met with an error stating, 'This site can’t be reached.' Is this a known issue within the Colab environment, and if so, are there recommended steps or solutions to resolve it? Any guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
enter image description here
I initiated a Streamlit session within a Google Colab notebook and used the provided link to view the application's output. I expected the link to lead me to a Streamlit interface displaying the output of my code. However, upon clicking the link, I was confronted with a browser error message stating, 'This site can’t be reached,' and I was unable to access the Streamlit output. I attempted refreshing the page and checking the link for accuracy but faced the same issue each time.
